# Copy a directory over http within a windows batch file

Tags: http, batch-file, copy

I need a command to use in a batch file, which copies the contents of a remote directory to a local directory over http.

For example to copy folder http ://path//folder to C:\folder

I need to do this without installing any additional tools.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does powershell/.net (or at least vbscript/jscript) counts as additional tool?

Comment: Powershell can be used.

Comment: We need to see what you have tried. How do you plan to obtain the directory index, as HTTP does not provide such a mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard way for an http server to list accessible directories.

For example I took http://unomoralez.com/content/files/catalog2/source/ as one of the common ways to list directory with http. Your site could look different though but there's no way for me tho know... (ther's a temp `list2.txt` file - you can remark its deletion to check the format of directory page and tell me if its not working. IF it is IIS could look like this: http://live.sysinternals.com/tools/)

the script downloads all content into `.\download_dir` (not recursive download) :

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /******  jscript comment ******

@echo off
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::       compile the script    ::::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
setlocal
if exist simpledownloader.exe goto :skip_compilation

set "frm=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\"
:: searching the latest installed .net framework
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%v in ('dir /b /s /a:d /o:-n "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v*"') do (
    if exist "%%v\jsc.exe" (
        rem :: the javascript.net compiler
        set "jsc=%%~dpsnfxv\jsc.exe"
        goto :break_loop
    )
)
echo jsc.exe not found && exit /b 0
:break_loop


call %jsc% /nologo /out:"simpledownloader.exe" "%~dpsfnx0"
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::       end of compilation    ::::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:skip_compilation

:: download the file


 :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 ::::just change the link and the file::::
 :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


 ::!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!:::
 simpledownloader.exe "http://unomoralez.com/content/files/catalog2/source/" "list2.txt"

 md download_dir >nul 2>&1

 for /f "skip=1 tokens=4 delims=>< " %%a in ('type list2.txt^| find /i "href" ')  do (
    simpledownloader.exe "http://unomoralez.com/content/files/catalog2/source/%%a" .\download_dir\%%a
)

del /q /f list2.txt


exit /b 0


****** end of jscript comment ******/

import System;
var arguments:String[] = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
var webClient:System.Net.WebClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
print("Downloading " + arguments[1] + " to " + arguments[2]);
try {
    webClient.DownloadFile(arguments[1], arguments[2]);
} catch (e) {

        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nProblem with downloading " + arguments[1] + " to " + arguments[2] + "Check if the internet address is valid");
        Console.ResetColor();
        Environment.Exit(5);
}
```

As you have `powershell` you also have `.net` so this code will  be executed without problems for you.

This was more or less a code that I already had but you can also check this -> https://code.google.com/p/curlie/ if you are familiar with `cURL` and create a hybrid jscript/.bat file.